# View All Columns Where Name Repeats

Tags: oracle

I've been asked to provide a list of all employees who are scheduled to take >6 trips. I need to have all the columns of their record showing for each trip.

I'm very new to SQL and don't have the logic down. So far I've been able to get a count:

```
SELECT SURNAME, GIVEN_NAME, COUNT(SURNAME)    
from EP_EVENT    
GROUP BY SURNAME, GIVEN_NAME HAVING COUNT(SURNAME) > 6;
```

But I need to see * not just SURNAME and GIVEN_NAME, none of the other columns contain the same information.

Help

Comment: Does the EP_EVENT table contain column like EMPLOYEE_ID? Think that it's wrong approach to group by SURNAMEs as they may be non-unique

Answer (score 2):

You could use windowed `COUNT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT e.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SURNAME, GIVEN_NAME) AS cnt
   FROM  EP_EVENT e
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 6;
```